# Why new rules in .gitignore were not applied making pull?

Tags: laravel, git

making pull from git I got errors:

```
$ git pull origin remote_branch
Password for 'https://myaccount@github.com': 
From https://github.com/client_name/project_name
 * branch            remote_branch   -> FETCH_HEAD
error: Your local changes to the following files would be overwritten by merge:
        package-lock.json
        public/mix-manifest.json
Please commit your changes or stash them before you merge.
error: The following untracked working tree files would be overwritten by merge:
        public/vendor/jsvalidation/js/jsvalidation.js
        public/vendor/jsvalidation/js/jsvalidation.js.map
        public/vendor/jsvalidation/js/jsvalidation.min.js
        public/vendor/jsvalidation/js/jsvalidation.min.js.map
        resources/views/vendor/jsvalidation/bootstrap.php
        resources/views/vendor/jsvalidation/bootstrap4.php
        resources/views/vendor/jsvalidation/uikit.php
        storage/framework/cache/data/c0/71/c071422490d526a8aada046adf3a9c9fa0593468
        storage/framework/cache/data/ec/c4/ecc49f49f4da6b940dcde13f0571e79c299871e6
Please move or remove them before you merge.
Aborting
```

Trying to salve in root .gitignore of my project I added 3 lines:

```
/node_modules
/public/hot

/public/vendor
/resources/views/vendor
/storage/framework/cache
...
```

I hide 3 directories which raised errors from git  and wonder why
it did not work and which steps have I to take?

**MODIFIED BLOCK :**
I try to delete file by file and whole directory and can not get why I got errors:

```
uset@ubuntuos:/project_path$ git rm public/vendor/jsvalidation/js/jsvalidation.js
fatal: pathspec 'public/vendor/jsvalidation/js/jsvalidation.js' did not match any files
uset@ubuntuos:/project_path$ git rm public/vendor
fatal: pathspec 'public/vendor' did not match any files
```

Checking I find my files and seems files path are valid:

```
uset@ubuntuos:/project_path$ cd public/vendor
uset@ubuntuos:/project_path/public/vendor$ ls -la
total 4
drwxrwxrwx 1 root root    0 Jun 12 07:39 .
drwxrwxrwx 1 root root 4096 Jun 18 10:40 ..
drwxrwxrwx 1 root root    0 Jun 12 07:39 jsvalidation
uset@ubuntuos:/project_path/public/vendor$ cd jsvalidation/js/
uset@ubuntuos:/project_path/public/vendor/jsvalidation/js$ ls -la
total 1076
drwxrwxrwx 1 root root      0 Jul  1 06:35 .
drwxrwxrwx 1 root root      0 Jun 12 07:39 ..
-rwxrwxrwx 1 root root 294122 Jul  1 06:35 jsvalidation.js
-rwxrwxrwx 1 root root 337252 Jul  1 06:35 jsvalidation.js.map
-rwxrwxrwx 1 root root  70759 Jul  1 06:35 jsvalidation.min.js
-rwxrwxrwx 1 root root 391072 Jul  1 06:35 jsvalidation.min.js.map
```

?

Thanks!

Comment: Just adding the files to .gitignore won't remove them from the repo, you have to do that as well. Unfortunately, that means they will also be removed for everyone else when they update.

Comment: All these directories are autigenerated with composer. I wonder why they are not ignored as I expected? Have I to use  git rm dirname for any of them ?

Comment: Yes, you can `git rm` them and they will be removed for everybody. Adding their names to `.gitignore` will prevent them from being added by accident. If the data is totally transient and can be recreated, go for it. Keeping different local versions around requires manual steps for everyone who pulls.

Comment: Pls look at MODIFIED BLOCK

Comment: Seems I set valid relative path. Why error?

Comment: I don't know, try `git rm -r` on directories

Comment: the same error with "-r" key. But what would be if too remove them all manually in krusader?

Comment: removing them manually (i.e. on the file system) is only one step, they also have to be deleted from Git's index. What does `git status public/vendor` say?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try git rm -r --cached ./ignored-directory

Comment: Got :  git rm -r --cached ./public/vendor
fatal: pathspec './public/vendor' did not match any files
   Did you mean this format ?